# Clear PageStorageKey when app back to foreground in Flutter

Tags: flutter, page-state

I have a `PageView` which contain some `CustomScrollView`. I'm using `PageStoreKey` to keep the scroll position of `CustomScrollView`. I want to reset all scroll position to 0 when my app went to the next day. Does have any ways to clear the `PageStoreKey` of my list?

#### Require steps:

- Start app at 23:50
- Scroll the `CustomScrollView` in page 1.
- Change to page 2.
- Scroll the `CustomScrollView` in page 2.
- Press home button (let app go to BG)
- Wait until 00:01 of the next day.
- Start app again (let app back to FG from BG)

#### My solution (but not good, I think)

Put the current day into `PageStoreKey` to separate the key.